# How to get the star during "Score Frenzy"

Tags: treasures-of-montezuma

What should I do exactly to gain the star during "Score Frenzy" in "The Treasures of Montezuma"? It gives me 15 seconds (well, it can be increased with upgrades) and I don't know what to do to get the star.

Comment: did you finally know how to do it?